# Spring context is not getting updated even after using DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, threadpool, spring-context

I ran into some problem with spring contexts and it's really made more confusing after reading all the articles.
So, here it is my use case:

I have an application running which needs user's authentication token passed in the request to use it in the the process I will run in background. This token is used to make rest api calls. At first, we were manually creating new thread and to pass on the context I was using  MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL strategy for spring context. But in latest release we started using thread pool. It worked after deployment but token was getting invalidating after a point because thread was not getting the latest context. I read articles and started using DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor  like below:

@Bean
public DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor delegate) {
return new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(delegate);
}

But I still have the same problem when I checked today. Now tomorrow I might bombarded with mails from tester with failing test cases. One thing I want to add that I am still using  MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL as strategy along with DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

First: You should not use `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL` together with pooled threads (to learn more, read [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6856))

Second: From my experience defining `DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor` as a `@Bean` won't work. The default executor will be still used.

You need to extend your `@EnableAsync @Configuration` from `AsyncConfigurer` interface and implement `getAsyncExecutor`, not annotating it with a `@Bean`. Working example:

```
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {
    private final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor defaultSpringBootAsyncExecutor;

    public AsyncConfig(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor defaultSpringBootAsyncExecutor) {
        this.defaultSpringBootAsyncExecutor = defaultSpringBootAsyncExecutor;
    }

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        return new DelegatingSecurityContextAsyncTaskExecutor(defaultSpringBootAsyncExecutor);
    }
}
```